# Android app not opening scrolling popup for single-line code block

Tags: bug, android-app

The Android app doesn't recognize that a long single-line code block needs to scroll. Here's an example of such a long block:

```
blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob blob long blob
```

It won't open the popup for me with the latest version from Play Store (21st Feb 2017). Is this intended behavior?